# How to create logic template and model in Class-Base-View base on the path pass by in Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm almost a month working and practicing my self in Django and I do really like it. But right now I have Three Class-Base View which have the same function displaying the list of different data base on the model I provide for them, Now what I want is that to create only one Class-Base View and render the `template_name` and `model` base on the url path passes? Since they are the same function. Is that possible to create?

Comment: Does your CBV has a ***create*** or ***update*** functionality?

Comment: No, only ListView.

Comment: @KimNicoleSabordo please add the source code of those 3 identical `ListView`s so we can bring better suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give the correct answer without more details. Actual solution might be different depending on things like:

1. Do you have just one template for all three views?
2. Do you have unique filtering logic in each class-based view or you just get all the objects?

and so on. But I can share kind of generic solution, which could be modified by your if needed.

**NOTE**: it wasn't tested, but should work in theory

---

**views.py**

```py
class VehicleListView(ListView):
    pass
```

**urls.py**

The main idea here is about `as_view` method of each CBV. It let you to set the value of an existent class attribute. For more information see here

https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3901b5899d746dc5b754115d94ce9a045b4db0a/django/views/generic/base.py#L63
https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3901b5899d746dc5b754115d94ce9a045b4db0a/django/views/generic/base.py#L45-L46

*get all elements for each model*

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('cars/', VehicleListView.as_view(model=Car)),
    path('bike/', VehicleListView.as_view(model=Bike)),
    path('boat/', VehicleListView.as_view(model=Boat)),

]
```

*simple custom queryset*

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('cars/', VehicleListView.as_view(queryset=Car.objects.all())),
    path('bike/', VehicleListView.as_view(queryset=Bike.objects.all())),
    path('boat/', VehicleListView.as_view(queryset=Boat.objects.all())),

]
```

*complex custom queryset*

```py
def get_cars(cbv_instance):
    pass

def get_bikes(cbv_instance):
    pass

def get_boats(cbv_instance):
    pass

urlpatterns = [
    path('cars/', VehicleListView.as_view(get_queryset=get_cars)),
    path('bike/', VehicleListView.as_view(get_queryset=get_bikes)),
    path('boat/', VehicleListView.as_view(get_queryset=get_boats)),

]
```

or even better - encapsulate that "queryset stuff" inside model managers and pass as simple `queryset` parameter like

```py
path('boat/', VehicleListView.as_view(queryset=Boat.objects.get_boats_for_today()))
```

(but in this case you wouldn't have access to CBV instance, i.e. to things like request).

**template**

The template name is generated based on the given model or given queryset. For example: `myapp/car_list.html` or `myapp/boat_list.html`. For more information refer to this function https://github.com/django/django/blob/f3901b5899d746dc5b754115d94ce9a045b4db0a/django/views/generic/list.py#L165-L191